# How to check for form submission in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

In my form, there are some fields, which I want to check before submitting the form. If there are errors, the form would not be submitted and the user would be alerted with an error.

For that purpose, I am trying to catch the event where the form is submitted, in php. I should get an alert with text "Submitted". However, I don't. What mistake am I doing?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo "<span>Submitted!</span>";
    sleep(2);
?>

<form action="next_page.php" method=post> 
*Other fields beside input*
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"> <br>
</form>
```

Comment: HTML5 `pattern` attribute or you could use JS. Oh and `submit` type!

Comment: Do you see a form element with the name of "submit" anywhere in that form? No? Neither do I. So how can you expect to see it in your code?

Comment: It also looks like you're mixing javaScript and PHP (unless you wrote your own alrt() function but based on the simplicity of this question I highly doubt that).

Comment: An alert? A Javascript alert? From your PHP script?!

Comment: there's no `alert` function in PHP

Comment: Yes I do have an input submit. Edited the question.

Comment: There is no such function as alert in php

Comment: Only client side form validation is not secure. You can use ajax to validate the form data on server side.

Comment: Some dudes woke up salty this morning...

Comment: alert() method of javascript not php. In php you can use echo() method.

Comment: `alert()` is a JAVASCRIPT function. Therefore it does nothing in your PHP, except it should be generating a Compile Error. LOOK IN THE PHP ERROR LOG

Comment: if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_MTHOD' ] == 'POST' ){
   echo 'submitted';
}

Comment: @DenisSlonovschi That doesn't work either.

Comment: @pythonic sorry, a typo, it's REQUEST_METHOD, not REQUEST_MTHOD. And by the way, try method="post" on the form method attribute, put it between commas

Comment: @DenisSlonovschi Did that, still doesn't work!

Comment: @pythonic does your file have a .php extension? Are you running your code on a live server or a virtual server on a local machine?

Comment: On a live server. The message is indeed recieved on the next page, but I want to catch it on the same page.

Comment: @pythonic You've been told multiple times that php can't do that, you need to use javascript or jQuery (AJAX).

Comment: @Epodax: Yup I am using jquery now, and it works like a charm :).

Answer (score 3):

`alert()` is not a function provided by PHP, so it will error.

You seem to be confusing it with JavaScript.

To output text from PHP you need to `echo` it or put it outside of `<?php ... >?` blocks. To run JavaScript, you need a `<script>` element.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
    <script> alert("Submitted!"); </script>
<?php
}
?>

<form action="next_page.php" method=post> 
    <!-- You also need to have a form control that matches the test you are doing -->
    <button name="submit" value="X">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is missing the `submit` type.
Also you need to `echo` the alert box, since `alert()` is NOT a PHP function.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo"<script>alert('Submitted!');</script>"; ?>

<form action="next_page.php" method=post>  
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Sub"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to accomplish what you would like to accomplish. Are you using any kind of framework? It might have built in for this. Generally it's not a bad idea to to rely on standard functions or libraries to do verification.

If not you will have to do it yourself and decide whenever you'd like it to be server-side (php) or user-side (javascript). Regardless you should verify it server-side to catch any malicious submits.

If we go with your example it might look like this for server-side php verification which echos its results back to the user. Beware that this is really, really insecure as it's using $_GET which might be modified etc.

```
<?php
$username = '';
$warning = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && strlen(trim($_POST['username'])) != 0){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        if(strlen($username) > 8){
            $warning = 'Only 8 characters allowed!';
        }else{
            header("Location: next_page.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $warning = 'Username is empty, please provide a valid name.';
    }
}
?>
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo($username); ?>" />
    <?php echo($warning); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This snippet would preserve input in case anything is wrong and only redirect to the next page if the data was valid. An example using jQuery could look like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.preventDefault demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <form action="form.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="text" name="username" id="formUsername" />
        <span id="warning"> </span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form").submit(function( event ) {
            var username = $("#formUsername").val().trim();

            if(username.length > 0 && username.length < 9){
                $("form").submit();
            }
            else if(username.length > 8)
            {
                $("#warning").text("More than 8 characters.");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
                $("#warning").text("Empty username?");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST` in your first example, also the form is still submitted via POST and your second line will throw a `UNDEFINED Variable` unless the username is set via the URL. (still in the first example only)

Comment: Thanks, I did improve it a bit. I was working with a different idea at first, hence the mixup with `$_GET`. It's only meant as a snipped to give someone an idea on what could be done. It has a lot of flaws.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to output a message on the same page after the form is submitted, not an alert.
The action attribute on the HTML form tag redirects you to the next_page.php. So leave the action attribute blank, and after you've validated all your fields use php header() function to redirect to next_page.php. Be aware not to output any of the message before the header() function, it will fail in this case.
Do smthing like this:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
    $err_message = '';
    //validate your fields
    if($_POST['yourfield'] == ''){
        $err_message = 'Please check your fields';
    }
    //other validations
    ...
    if($err_message == ''){
       //redirect to your next page
       header('Location:next_page.php');
       //prevent further code execution
       exit();
    }
    //output your message
    echo $err_message;
}
?>

<form action="" method=post> 
*Other fields beside input*
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"> <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways you can do it.

Here again is an alternative if you wanted to keep it based under an echo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo '<script>alert("Submitted!");</script>';
}
?>

<form action="" method=post>
    *Other fields beside input*
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"> <br>
</form>
```

EDIT: Generally I try to leave the PHP in the top of the same page rather than having it point elsewhere as there's not much need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was using Jquery, with something like as shown below.

```
$('#form1').submit(
    function() {
        //your validation rules here
        var email = $('#YourEMail').val()
        if(!validEmail(email))
        {
            $('#invalidAlert').html('<i>Invalid e-mail address!</i>')
            return false;
        }
        else 
            return true;
    });
```